# How can I Restore the settings line above the Krita screen

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, configuration, amd-graphics, crash

I installed KRITA 5.1 on my system/ ubuntu studio 20. First all fine; then I connected my drawing tablet to the pc and opened a new drawing. It opened and the setting line was gone. Since that time I cannot restore the settings, what means I cannot fixe the preferences.

I'm running thru the web, but nothing works. I killed KRITA and installed it new - allways the same.

I'm sure, it is my error, but my be someone can help me to fixe the settings. Thank you/ cico2018

**my system:**

```
Prozessor       : AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Hauptspeicher       : 16399MB (3047MB used)
Maschinen-Typ       : Desktop
Betriebssystem      : Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Benutzername        :
Date/Time       : Mi 08 Mär 2023 10:49:04 CET
```

**-Anzeige-**

```
Auflösung       : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL-Renderer     : AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (NAVI10, DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-144-lowlatency, LLVM 12.0.0)
X11-Hersteller      : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio-Geräte-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the settings and the setting itself to default here are some things you can try:

1. Go to to krita in `~/.config` then you might have to to press ctrl + h to show hidden files, then delete or rename the `kritarc` file, then restart krita to see if the settings are restored.
2. Check if your drawing tablet is properly configured in KRITA. Go to 'Settings' -> 'Configure Krita' be sure that your tablet is well connected or try to reinstall your drivers
3. Try creating a new user accout and try Krita with it, that will help you to know if the problem is there
4. Uninstall Krita and the congiration files, use these commands:

`sudo apt-get purge krita`

`rm -rf ~/.config/krita`

`sudo apt-get install krita`